# Loop for container class c++

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I have this loop

```
for(int i=0;i<vec1.size();++i)
{
    if(vec1[i]==*p)
    {
        vec1[i]=*p;
        cout<<"element updated"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"push_back"<<endl;
        vec1.push_back(*p);
    }
}
```

I'm inserting objects in container class and I've overloaded the == to check two parameters inside the object and if they match I want to update the them and if they don't match I want to put them in the vector, but I don't seem to be able to properly populate my vector, when I do vec1.size() I get 0 even when I insert 3 objects.

Comment: So you are confirming that your push_backs are being called?  I assume you have hard-coded some push_backs to verify the 3 insertions you cite?

Comment: what is p pointing to? I assume it's a pointer.

Comment: `if(vec1[i]==*p) vec1[i]=*p;` is pointless.  You are checking to see if the item at `vec[i]` is equal to `p` and if it is, then you set it to `p`.  You set it to the same value you just confirmed it to be.  Is this what you intended to do?

Comment: @John Dibling: The question explicitly says that operator== is overloaded to look at two specific fields. I take that to mean there are others that could meaningfully be updated. I won't call it a good design, but it's not a no-op as you say.

Comment: Don't push new elements into vector when you are iterating over it..

Comment: I havent hardcoded for push_back to check anything yet, and *p is a pointer to a person object this is in an add method in container class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is that your `if` is *inside* your search loop. Your `if` will never be executed, because your loop body never runs, because your `.size()` will never be greater than 0.

Try this:

```
// UNTESTED
std::vector<person> vec1;
add(person *p) {
  std::vector<person>::iterator it = std::find(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), *p);
  if(it == vec1.end())
    vec1.push_back(*p);
  else
    *it = *p;
}
```

Or, if you really want to code the loop by hand:

```
// UNTESTED
std::vector<person> vec1;
add(person *p) {
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<vec1.size();++i) {
    if(vec1[i] == *p)
      break;
  }
  if(i == vec1.size())
    vec1.push_back(*p);
  else
    vec1[i] = *p;
}
```

---

Of course, you might consider changing your container. Using a `std::map` would shorten your code and reduce the time it takes to manipulate large data sets.

```
std::map<std::string, person> map1;
add(person *p) {
  map1[p->name] = *p;
}
```

Comment: If you really intended to invoke `vec[i] = *p` for its non-obvious side effects, then my code above must be modified. Leave a comment and I'll update it, **if** that is what you meant.

Comment: Yeah, the reason I want to invoke 'vec[i]=*p' is because I want to update the elements inside say I have 'person p1("tom")' and then person 'p2("tom" "32323")' and i have 'c.add(&p1)' 'c.add(&p2)' i want only the 2nd one to remain inside the vector

Comment: I think you misunderstood me there, I need to populate a vector with objects, and if an objects happens to have the same attributes(vec1[i]==p*) then i execute vec1[i]=*p, if it doesn't find any object with same attributes I just add it to the vector

Comment: I *think* that is exactly what my code does. My code inserts or updates one object into your vector. My code would live inside `.add()`; you would invoke my code once for each time you wanted to add a person.

Comment: Thank you man, thanks to you I was able to find a faulty statement in my == overloading and now it all works fine and dandy cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When the vec1 starts from empty, the for loop is not going to run. So you want to have at least one element in vec1 to start with. How about add this:

```
vec1.push_back(*p);
for(int i=0;i<vec1.size();++i){//the rest}
```

Comment: The issue with this is that it will invoke vec1.push_back(*p) every time i call the member function

Comment: How about this: if(vec1.empty()) vec1.push_back(*p);